# Highcharts stacked columns with variable width

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'am trying to make stack columns with variable width. Have a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/calfzhou/TUt2U/) , but i can't make column stack.
I think, i need use stacking: true and in data write something like this
 `data: [x:2, y:10, 2, 3, 5]` where's  `2,3,5` stack value. 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you have an example of the expected output? I am having a hard time visualizing this.

Comment: @wergeld, [output](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/) something like this but with x - values show a column width

Comment: the column/bar width is set per series. So you can make all `John` series points have the same width. You cannot set a width per point - all points in a series have the same width. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5fjPw/

Comment: @wergeld, that's right, i can't make it for all point in a series but i think in  [example](http://jsfiddle.net/calfzhou/TUt2U/) if make data `{ name: 'A', x: 5.2, y: 2.3,},{ name: 'A', x: 5.2, y: 5.6 }` Checking by the same name and the same value of x and draw the second column above the first.We get a stacked.

Comment: No, this will not work. You are now labeling two series with the same name. You need to do something like: {name: 'A', data: [{x: 5.2, y: 2.3}, {x: 5.2, y: 5.6}]`

Comment: It still would really help to see what your expected output is supposed to look like. You are asking about stacking columns but your series type is area. What should this look like?

Comment: @wergeld, i see my graph like this [output expected](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=bce422745705344e03eac0a04c288a70)

Comment: @wergeld, (http://jsfiddle.net/jLnnJ/) i make staked but  now have a problem with color and legend.

Comment: If you don't want duplicated items, user `series.linkedTo` option.